# AngularJS Controller 'ngSwitch', required by directive 'ngSwitchDefault', can't be found with table

Tags: angularjs

I am currently writing an Angular application which is based on another application. I copied a part of the working code but it gives this error when I try to run it:

```
Controller 'ngSwitch', required by directive 'ngSwitchDefault', can't be found!
```

This is the code

```
<div ng-switch on="arg == 0">
    <span ng-switch-when="true">-</span>
    <table ng-switch-default border="0">
            //input
    </table>
</div>
```

When I change the table directive in to something else the code does work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It seems like this snippet is working for me http://plnkr.co/edit/LUmop603G5xnux0Ai0eG?p=preview . It looks like the problem is with some other part of your project.

Comment: it works if i put only put 'table' in it like you did, but it does not work with e.g. <thead>. It still triggers the error with both inputs. Where should I be looking to find the error?

Comment: It would help a lot if you could reproduce your issue on plunker. I also found this thread that may be related https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3661

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce it yet on plunker but I could make it work if I put the table inside a div like this: <div ng-switch-default><table border="0"></table></div>, but I don't think this is the way it should be..